# how to get number of socket connections using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is there a way to get the number of connections in socket.io?

I want to display a message on my site that says "x users connected right now"

Basically if I did a socket.broadcast I want to count how many connections that would go to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
io.sockets.clients().length
```

Basically io.sockets.clients() returns Socket instances of all clients. If you're using rooms then you should better use

```
io.sockets.clients('room').length
```

because it returns socket instances of all clients in a particular room

Comment: if the same user establishes different connections for many events, is clients still just 1 for that user?

Comment: What I stated above returns number of connected sockets. So If you've opened 5 tabs in a browser then it will return 5. The server maintains sockets by their IDs. If you want to count them as a single user then you should better look for another technique as count users by their IP addresses

Comment: ok, that's fine. i wasn't sure if there is only one socket per session.

Comment: Yes there is one socket per session but if you want to count number of different users then you should count them by their IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Using this code Server site



 var noOfUser=[];
      socket.on('someEventFromClient',function(data){
               //User name must unique
               socket.username=data.username;
               noOfUser.push(data.username);
//Now you can emit no of user to client are any where
                                         console.log('NO of user:'+noOfUser.length);
              });

            socket.on('disconnect',function(){
                       for(var i=0;i<noOfUser;i++)
                             {
                                       if(noOfUser[i]==socket.username)
                                           {
                                                noOfUser.splice(i,1);
                                               }
                                            //Now you can emit no of user to client are any where
                                         console.log('NO of user:'+noOfUser.length);
                                    }
             });
```

Client side:
when user connect socket server emit this event
socket.emit('someEventFromCLient',{username:'someuniqueID'});